# Why does Threading::Monitor::TryEnter succeed more than once?

Tags: .net, multithreading, unit-testing, c++-cli, monitor

I'm trying to secure some multi-threaded code and am in the process of adding unit tests to prove I've fixed corruption we'd previously been seeing.

In doing so though I've come across some unexpected behaviour. Why does the following code succeed when [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42h9d380.aspx) indicate that `TryEnter` should only return true when the function has achieved an exclusive lock?

```
const int msToWaitForLock = 1;
Object^ syncObj = gcnew Object();
bool gotLock = Threading::Monitor::TryEnter(syncObj, msToWaitForLock); // <-- this succeeds as expected
bool gotSecondLock = Threading::Monitor::TryEnter(syncObj, msToWaitForLock); // <-- but why the heck does this succeed?!
```

Comment: `Monitor.Enter` is re-entrant, if you are calling it *from the same thread.* [See here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx) under "Nested Locking."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Documentation says

> It is legal for the same thread to invoke Enter more than once without
>   it blocking

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz(v=vs.110)

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something in the question, should not both of those calls succeed, since they are being made from the same thread?

Therefore, if you had made them from separate threads, I would expect the second to fail.

Comment: No you're not missing anything. I hadn't realised it wouldn't block when called from the same thread. There goes my nice simple unit test!